# Can mold grow on copper pipes?

Tags: biochemistry

Couple months ago noticed something was literally, for lack of a better term, eating paint off of lead pipes.  And I noticed joints in copper pipe seemed to be "leaking" flux. Now all the water in my house causes lips and tongue to feel as if they have cold sores or anesthesised.  taste could be rusty.

Comment: Not mold. But you may be getting metal poisoning, get good advice. Seriously.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! We encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks! 

Answer (score 0):

Copper inhibits growth of organisms. See " Antimicrobial properties of copper" in Wikipedia.